# Get relative path to image in another project in same solution

Tags: c#, silverlight, uri

I have a Silverlight project with several projects in my solution. I want to get a relative path
to an image in project A from project B inside my helper C# class.

solution

-Project A

```
  -Helper.cs
```

-Project B

```
  -image.jpg
```

Helper.cs need a reference to image.jpg

I can't add a reference to prj A from prj B.

Can I do something like:

Uri uri = new Uri("/project.name.projectA;image.jpg", UriKind.Relative);

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/ResourceFile.xaml

Replace *ReferencedAssembly* with the name of the referenced assembly and *ResourceFile.xaml* with the name of the file in it which has build type resource.

[Resource File Pack URIs Referenced Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Referenced_Assembly)

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get the path to a specific file inside the resource file, if I have several images?

Comment: What do you mean specific file inside resource file? There are no nested files. Every image is a resource file.

Comment: Okay, I thought a resource file had be be a .xaml file. So I can simply do

pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/image.png 

for the path to the image file?

Comment: @user643017 yes you can reference any file like that just make sure their build type in properties window is set as Resource.

Comment: Okay so now it works, using the following code:

newUri = new Uri("/some.path.projectA;component/image.png", UriKind.Relative);